# Tables and how to manage data

Tags: html, css

I have a table:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the cells to break at a certain width so that it displays:

```
1 2
3 4
```

I tried using `td:nth-child()`, but couldn't get past changing the color of the `td` or having them all vertical.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You have an extra `</td` tag  in the second to last row of your code, when it should be a `</tr>` tag.  Try fixing that and seeing if it helps.  I'm unable to reproduce your issue -- perhaps you have something in your CSS?

Comment: Sorry, yeah i saw it thanks but thats not the problem.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle.js with all of your code and see if the issue persists?

Comment: What do you mean a certain width? Like when the screen shrinks or when the table grows?

Comment: Close your TR tag and add another. TR stands for "Table Row". Tell it where one ends and where the next starts.

Comment: I would play with `td {  display: block  }` when the screen gets smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting screen size to your need, currently set to 768px

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr class="row1">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row2">
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  tr {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) { 
  tr {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that answer worker for me, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add explantation for the solution. Also your code is faulty: it lacks an opening `tr` after the first closing `tr`.

Comment: This does not answer the question. However the question is unclear, too.